# Magento 1.5.1.0 API - customer_address.list returns error

Tags: php, web-services, api, magento

I'm calling Magento 1.5.1.0 API with http://****/api/soap/?wsdl (version 1)

I can login to the webservice, I can get customer.info, customer_address.info etc.
But I can't get customer_address.list to work.

I'm using the following code:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://***/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiuser', 'apipass');
$newCustomerId = 178475;
// This works fine
var_dump($proxy->call($sessionId, 'customer.info', $newCustomerId));
// This should work according to the API doc. But doesn't?
var_dump($proxy->call($sessionId, 'customer_address.list', $newCustomerId));
```

The error message in the second var_dump is:

> Call to a member function getId() on a non-object

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Regards,

Lars Hansen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be you have a custom module that got an/some error for getId() function.

My example is working.

```
try {//customer.info
        $result = $cli->call($session_id,'customer.info',$_customerId);
        print_r($result);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e->faultstring."\n");
    }

    try {//customer_address.list
        $result = $cli->call($session_id,'customer_address.list',$_customerId);
        print_r($result);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e->faultstring."\n");
    }
```

Or it might be your $newCustomerId is not exists on your customer_entity table;

Do **try** for debugging the error.

Correct me if i'm wrong

^^